# I'm confused about webcam picture resolution

Tags: webcam, pictures

I want to buy a webcam, in the product spec it has:
Still image:Up to 16 Megapixel, 4608x3456 (software interpolated)
Image sensor:1/6"CMOS, 640×480 pixels

Is it real 16MP camera? or with an specified software it resize image to 4608x3456?
I want to use such big picture in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope - it's 0.3 megapixels.  [Software interpolation](http://www.americaswonderlands.com/image_resizing.htm) stretches and blurs the image, but make no mistake: it's adding data where there wasn't any before.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that it is a real 16 MP camera (at least I've never seen a webcam that does that resolution; correct me if I'm wrong), probably - as it says on the specs - it's a 640x480 image which is interpolated to a larger resolution.